# UIlabel text color depending upon gradient color indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

im doing application where i need to show high risk (red color) to low risk(yellow color) means a strip starting from red color to another many colors in middle and finally ends in green color...if my weight percentage is 90% then i need to show green color for the text 90...and similarly if weight percentage is 25% then i need show 25 as red color and etc depending upon percentage... so how could i do this making uilabel text color depending upon percentage???
give some sample code,,

Thanks in advance...

Comment: we're not code monkeys. show what you've tried or what your idea is or something. We aren't going to write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

how are you calculating the percentage. Here is what I assume you are trying to do. Based on some formula/logic, you are calculating some percentage. Now if the percentage is x you want to show this x value in some particular color to the user. If it is so, you can do this,

```
if(weight==25)
{
label.text = @"25";
label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

It will really help if you can elucidate better on what your are trying to accomplish. Your question doesn't seem to spell it all.

Comment: he wants the label to be a gradient with a certain percentage a certain color, I think. (Could be wrong, hard to tell)

Comment: Is it some kind of scale or something? If it is so, may be you could post some image of it drawn in MSPaint or something for us to better understand your problem.

Comment: @jesse naugher : please refer this link for the image i said and which i will be using like this ..depending upon percentage is if i move indicator over that value i need my text as same pointed color

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://www.fuelyourcreativity.com/files/2008/12/rgb-gradient.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.fuelyourcreativity.com/3-deadly-sins-of-print-design/&usg=__ZLUv3lP0cl9B1vXKhyaawb2EFQs=&h=100&w=585&sz=31&hl=en&start=0&zoom=1&tbnid=-dyMkOh9tW4pXM:&tbnh=37&tbnw=216&ei=PVbLTdC3JIH0swPE2eifAw&prev=/search%3Fq%3Drgb%2Bcolor%2Bgradient%26um%3D1%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DN%26biw%3D968%26bih%3D640%26tbm%3Disch&um=1&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=245&vpy=154&dur=271&hovh=78&hovw=457&tx=253&ty=48&page=1&ndsp=12&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0

Answer (score 0):

if(weight >=90)[label setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

Answer (score 0):

Change the values of green and red color, keep the blue at 0 and alpha at 1. `UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.-(weight/100.) green:(weight/100.) blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];`